# How to synchronize the spellcheck dictionary in IntelliJ IDEA to different workstations?

Tags: dictionary, intellij-idea, spell-checking

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for a project which I develop on a laptop as well as on a desktop machine. Synchronizing the code via subversion and the built-in version-control-support is a no-brainer.

Since we have a lot of german comments in the code, I find my self adding words to the custom dictionary a lot which is necessary even though I installed a german dictionary, because in the german language you can build nearly infinite words by simple connecting existing words to each other. Now my problem is, that I will have to do the exact same thing again on the other machine, since the dictionary is not synchronized.

Is there a way to synchronize the added words? Put them into a file somehow, such that I can synchronize them with subversion? I didn't find anything in the Ide-Settings, there is only a list of words, but no text field to a file.

[image: Settings in IntelliJ IDEA for Spelling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your `.idea` folder the directory `dictionaries` inside you will have a `UserName.xml` file (mine is `Marco.xml` for example) which contains your custom words.

Just put it in the vcs

Answer (score 4):

In addition to synchronizing on a project level, as Marco Acierno shows in his answer, you can add additional dictionaries to IDEA to work across all projects. In your screen shot you will see a "dictionaries" tab. On that tab you can add additional dictionary directories. All `*.dic` files in the directory are are added. This is very useful to create a dictionary of business domain words or, in your case, other languages. You could simply add a [German.dic dictionary file](https://www.google.com/#q=german.dic+file).

You can even combine this with a version control strategy. Create a simple project in your version control that holds the dictionary file(s). Then as new words are encountered, team members can add them to it and commit. Then have a simple VCS update/pull/fetch script/task configured on your local PC to run every x minutes/hours so you automatically get updates as people add to the file. The one downside is that these files are read on IDE start-up and are not watched by the IDE for changes. So you won't see any updates until an IDE restart. But it can still be useful for a dictionary that is fairly "stable".

Comment: Thank you Mark for your comment. I know about this and am using it already. Unfortunately a German dictionary is not enough due to the possibility of combining words in German (as explained in my question). Therefore I am using the "rightglick --> add word to dictionary"-feature a lot and am looking for a way to synchronize theses added words.